# How to pass an ObjectId into a POST request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to make a `One-To-Many` relationship between two tables(Group and Movement tables) using node js (Express) and mongo DB. I already have a `group Id` coming from the Group table on my side, my question is, how can I save a movement( **see point 3** ) with that `group Id` I have. I tried passing `groupId: req.body.group._id` and 
 `groupId: req.body.group` but I am never able to populate that variable

This are the two entities I've created:

**1) GROUP ENTITY**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const GroupSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    limit: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    movement: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Movement' }],
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Group", GroupSchema)
```

**2) MOVEMENT ENTITY**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const MovementSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    value: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    group: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Movement", MovementSchema)
```

This is my movement router where I make the endpoints (**Actual problem is here**)

**3) MovementRoute**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const verify = require('./verifyToken');
const User = require('../model/User');
const Group = require('../model/Group');
const Movement = require('../model/Movement');

// Create Movement
router.post('/', verify, async (req, res) => {
    const post = new Movement({
        description: req.body.description,
        value: req.body.value,
        groupId: req.body.group._id //**tried this**
    });

    try {
        const savedMovement = await post.save()
        res.status(200).send(res.json({ data: savedMovement }));
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(res.json({ message: error }));
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Request sent**

```
{
    "description":"group1",
    "value":"233",
    "group":"5e506f3c56233d08f79bc8f3"
}
```

Comment: If you're not sending an ID in the post request nothing will live there. I think this issue has more to do with the request you are sending. Can you update the question with the request you are sending to that route?

Comment: Question edited with the request @MattOestreich

Comment: In the route handler, what does `console.log(req.body)` give you if you put it before `const post = new Movement({...` ?  You should just be able to do `goupId: req.body.group`

Comment: {
  description: 'group1',
  value: '233',
  group: '5e506f3c56233d08f79bc8f3'
}

Comment: Ok cool. So now if you do `console.log(req.body["group._id"])` what does it give you?  It looks like you'll need to do `groupId: req.body["group._id"]`

Comment: And in the collection (in mogo db database) it does not appear

Comment: let me try it out

Comment: Wait.. you just changed your comment... if `console.log(req.body)` give you this: `{ description: 'group1', value: '233', group: '5e506f3c56233d08f79bc8f3' }` you should be able to do `group: req.body.group`

Comment: it worked :) thanks a lot for your great help :)

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear it - I put an answer to make it more visible to other users. Please feel free to mark it as the accepted answer if I helped you :) Cheers!

Comment: Done :) Thanks..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208295/discussion-between-jose-nobre-and-matt-oestreich).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `console.log(req.body)` gives you this:

```js
{ 
    description: 'group1', 
    value: '233', 
    group: '5e506f3c56233d08f79bc8f3' 
}
```

..you should be able to do this:

```js
router.post('/', verify, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body) // --> { description: 'group1', value: '233', group: '5e506f3c56233d08f79bc8f3' } 

    const post = new Movement({
        description: req.body.description,
        value: req.body.value,
        groupId: req.body.group
        // groupId: req.body.group._id //**tried this**
    });

    try {
        const savedMovement = await post.save()
        res.status(200).send(res.json({ data: savedMovement }));
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(res.json({ message: error }));
    }
});
```